# Parsing XML-Like log file

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a log file which records events as follows. I would like convert each event into a PSCustomobject. It kinda looks like XML but casting xml to the Get-Content for the file gives me an error:

Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node."

```
<event date='Jan 06 01:46:16' severity='4' hostName='ABC' source='CSMFAgentPolicyManager' module='smfagent.dll' process='AeXNSAgent.exe' pid='1580' thread='1940' tickCount='306700046' >
  <![CDATA[Setting wakeup time to 3600000 ms (Invalid DateTime) for policy: DefaultWakeup]]>
</event>
```

Here is the piece of code I have so far

```
   <#
.EXAMPLE    
source    : MaintenanceWindowMgr
process   : AeXNSAgent.exe
thread    : 8500
hostName  : ABC
severity  : 4
tickCount : 717008140
date      : Jan 10 19:45:00
module    : PatchMgmtAgents.dll
pid       : 11984
CData     : isAbidingByMaintenanceWindows() - yes
#>
$logpath = Join-Path $env:ProgramData 'Symantec\Symantec Agent\logs\Agent.log'
$hash=[ordered]@{};
$log = get-content $logpath | % {

    ## handle Event start
    ## sample: <event date='Jan 10 18:45:00' severity='4' hostName='ABC' source='MaintenanceWindowMgr' module='PatchMgmtAgents.dll' process='AeXNSAgent.exe' pid='11984' thread='8500' tickCount='713408140' >
    if ($_ -match '^<event') {

        if ($hash) {                
            ## Convert the hastable to PSCustomObject before clearing it
            New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
            $hash.Clear()
        }

        $line = $_ -replace '<event ' -replace ' >' -split "'\s" -replace "'"               
        $line | % { 

            $name,$value=$_ -split '='                
            $hash.$name=$value
        }        
    }

    ## handle CData
    ## Sample: <![CDATA[Schedule Software Update Application Task ({A1939DC8-DA4A-4E46-9629-0500C2383ECA}) triggered at 2014-01-10 18:50:00 -5:00]]>
    if ($_ -match '<!') {
        $hash.'CData' = ($_ -replace '<!\[CDATA\[' -replace '\]\]>$').ToString().Trim()
    }
}
  $log
```

Unfortunately, the object is not in the form I would want it.

```
$log|gm


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType Definition                    
----        ---------- ----------                    
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method     type GetType()                
ToString    Method     string ToString()
```

When I try to collect all the objects from the output, I am losing the NoteProperties that are generated when I convert the hash to PSCustomObject

```
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                                                                                                                                     
----        ----------   ----------                                                                                                                                     
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                                 
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                              
GetType     Method       type GetType()                                                                                                                                 
ToString    Method       string ToString()                                                                                                                              
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                                 
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                              
GetType     Method       type GetType()                                                                                                                                 
ToString    Method       string ToString()                                                                                                                              
CData       NoteProperty System.String CData=isAbidingByMaintenanceWindows() - yes                                                                                      
date        NoteProperty System.String date=Jan 10 18:45:00                                                                                                             
hostName    NoteProperty System.String hostName=ABC                                                                                                             
module      NoteProperty System.String module=PatchMgmtAgents.dll                                                                                                       
pid         NoteProperty System.String pid=11984                                                                                                                        
process     NoteProperty System.String process=AeXNSAgent.exe                                                                                                           
severity    NoteProperty System.String severity=4                                                                                                                       
source      NoteProperty System.String source=MaintenanceWindowMgr                                                                                                      
thread      NoteProperty System.String thread=8500                                                                                                                      
tickCount   NoteProperty System.String tickCount=713408140
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What would you like the output object to look like?

Comment: I would like to create a PSCustomObject which has all these name=value pairs as property=values.

Comment: I am guessing problem is that HashTable is unordered and therefore the objects initial objects I create are fine but they are not ordered, and hence cannot be represented by a single PSObject array, I will need to sort them first

Comment: What version of Powershell are you running?

Comment: I am running version 4.

Comment: Then you can use $hash=[ordered]@{};

Comment: Umm, how? I know that syntax, but not sure how to implement it in my code above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44991/discussion-between-adil-h-and-mjolinor)

Comment: If you include a complete sample of the logfile(replace sensitive info), we might help you finding out how to make it xml-castable. The sample you provided is xml-castable, so there must be some of the other elements that's causing the error, or the way you tried to cast it.

Comment: Thanks @FrodeF. the sample I provided just kept repeating itself but as I mentioned simply [xml](gc $logfile) gave me an error. ansgar-wiechers' response below fixed the issue though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML files must have a single root (or `documentElement`) node. Since your log file seems to contain multiple `<event>` tags without a common root element you can add the missing `documentElement` like this:

```psh
$logpath  = Join-Path $env:ProgramData 'Symantec\Symantec Agent\logs\Agent.log'
[xml]$log = "<logroot>$(Get-Content $logpath)</logroot>"
```

After that you can process your log with the usual methods, e.g.:

```psh
$fmt = 'MMM dd HH:mm:ss'

$log.SelectNodes('//event') |
  select @{n='date';e={[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.date, $fmt, $null)}},
         severity, hostname, @{n='message';e={$_.'#cdata-section'}}
```

If you prefer custom objects you can easily create them like this:

```psh
$fmt = 'MMM dd HH:mm:ss'

$log.SelectNodes('//event') | % {
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'Date'     = [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.date, $fmt, $null)
    'Severity' = $_.severity
    'Hostname' = $_.hostname
    'Message'  = $_.'#cdata-section'
  }
}
```

Comment: I do prefer PSCustomObject as it is easier to play with later on but this is a pretty cool trick, thank you! And I just realized I can easily convert $log.logroot.event to PSCustomObject without dealing with all regex. Love this!

Answer (score 1):

Using your split method:

```
$hash = [ordered]@{}
$regex = '^<event (.+) >$'
$lines = (gc $file) -match $regex -replace $regex,'$1'
foreach ($line in $lines)
 {
         $hash.Clear() 
         $line -split "'\s" -replace "'" |
         foreach {
                   $name,$value=$_ -split '='                
                   $hash.$name=$value
                 }

        [PSCustomObject]$hash 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the syntax. I initially thought [ordered] was not working but that was a red-herring. Because each event includes 3 lines (start event + metadata, CData, Close event), I had logic there to capture CData and there was a problem with the first hash object causing an empty object to be created, and throwing off the result.

Comment: If objective is just to spit out a custom object for every start event + metadata line, the CData and Close event lines can just be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought my problem was with the original hash not being sorted but later figured out where the actual problem was. The code below caused an initial PSCustomObject without any NoteProperty to be created:

```
  if ($hash) { .... }
```

Even a just initialized hash satisfied that as shown below:

```
PS H:\> $myhash=[ordered]@{}
PS H:\> if ($myhash) {"yay"}
yay
```

so to fix it, I simply changed the check

```
# CData is the last record, if hash has it, it's ready to convert to PSCustomObject
if ($hash.CData) { ... }
```

Here is the updated code:

```
   $hash=[ordered]@{}        
    $logpath = Join-Path $env:ProgramData 'Symantec\Symantec Agent\logs\Agent.log'       
    Get-Content $logpath | % {

        ## handle Event start            
        if ($_ -match '^<event') {       
            # CData is the last record, if hash has it, it's ready to convert to PSCustomObject
            if ($hash.CData) {                        
                ## Convert the hastable to PSCustomObject before clearing it
                [PSCustomObject]$hash                
                $hash.Clear()
            }

            ## sample: <event date='Jan 10 18:45:00' severity='4' hostName='ABC' source='MaintenanceWindowMgr' module='PatchMgmtAgents.dll' process='AeXNSAgent.exe' pid='11984' thread='8500' tickCount='713408140' >
            $line = $_ -replace '<event ' -replace ' >' -split "'\s" -replace "'"               
            $line | % { 
                        $name,$value=$_ -split '='                               
                            $hash.$name=$value                        
            }        
        }

        ## handle CData
        ## Sample: <![CDATA[Schedule Software Update Application Task ({A1939DC8-DA4A-4E46-9629-0500C2383ECA}) triggered at 2014-01-10 18:50:00 -5:00]]>
        if ($_ -match '<!') {
            $hash.'CData' = ($_ -replace '<!\[CDATA\[' -replace '\]\]>$').ToString().Trim()
        }
    }
```

Thanks @mjolinor for helpful comments!