# Why casting this string into XML doesn't work?

Tags: xml, powershell

Why this casting works:

```psh
$xml=[xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<catalogue>
  <products>
    <product id="pdt1">
      <metas>
      </metas>
    </product>
    <product id="pdt2">
      <metas>
      </metas>
    </product>    
  </products>
</catalogue>
'@
```

but not this one:

```
$projs=@'
<proj code="P_001" C="true" S="true" t="T1"/><proj code="P_002" C="true" S="false" t="T1"/><proj code="P_003" C="true" S="true" t="T1"/><proj code="P_004" C="true" S="true" t="T1"/>
'@

$xml_string="<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""iso-8859-1""?>$($projs)" 

$xml=[xml]$xml_string
```

The error is:

```
Cannot convert value "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><proj code="P_001" C="true" S="true" t="T1"/><proj code="P_002" C="true" S="false" t="T1"/><proj code="P_003" C="true" S="true" t="T1"/><proj code="P_004" 
C="true" S="true" t="T1"/>" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument".
Error: "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node."
```

My question is WHY, not HOW.

Comment: In particular, this answer explains why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21063085/3905079

Comment: @briantist OK you're right

Comment: Your XML is not valid XML so the parser won't load it.